# C# ServiceStack.Text analyze stream of json

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, servicestack-text

I am creating a json deserializer. I am deserializing a pretty big json file (25mb), which contains a lot of information. It is an array for words, with a lot of duplicates. With `NewtonSoft.Json`, I can deserialize the input as stream:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"myfile.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Read untill I find the narrow subset I need and start parsing and analyzing them directly
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader); //Analyze this object
    }
}
```

This allows me to keep reading small parts of the json and analyze it and check for duplicates etc.

If I want to do the same with `ServiceStack.Text`. I am doing something like:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"myfile.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    var result = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<MyObject>(sr);
}
```

`MyObject` only contains the subset of the json I am interested in, but this creates a massive overhead, as I will get a big array that contains a lot of duplicates.

In the first method I can filter these away immediately and thus not keeping them in memory.

The memory footprint between the two are (this includes the console program overhead):

- NewtonSoft: 30mb
- ServiceStack.Text: 215mb

And the time is:

- NewtonSoft: 2.5s
- ServiceStack.Text: 1.5s

The memory footprint is quite important, as I will be processing a lot of these.

I do understand that the ServiceStack method will give me the security of TypeSafety, but the memory footprint is more important for me.

As I can see that `ServiceStack.Text` is a lot faster, so I would like to know if I am able to recreate `NewtonSoft` example, but with `ServiceStack.Text`?

**Edit** (Added the object I try to parse):

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<List<Word>> Words { get; set; }
}

public class Word
{
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string W { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string P { get; set; }
}
```

In my test file (which is representative of use case) it has 29000 words, but only around 8500 unique words. I am only analyzing this data, so I cannot change the structure of it. It is a file containing arrays of arrays of words.

Comment: Can you give an idea of what `MyObject` looks like?  Is the data you are processing getting stored in some sort of collection?  If so, you might be able to do something with a custom collection.

Comment: @dbc I have added the MyObject class to the question now.

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsonSerializer.Generic.cs#L41) it looks like `JsonSerializer<T>.DeserializeFromReader(TextReader reader)` just loads the entire JSON into a string: `return DeserializeFromString(reader.ReadToEnd());`.  And internally the various [parse methds](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/DeserializeListWithElements.cs#L120) work with strings.  So, I don't *think* so.

Comment: With Json.NET, you might try deserializing each individual object to a `Word` using the technique from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32237819/3744182).  [This page](http://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/) claims LINQ-to-JSON is 20% slower than deserialization.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26380184/3744182) for more ideas.

Comment: @dbc that is how I am doing it with Json.NET. I was just wondering if I could do the same with ServiceStack.Text. I am running this analysis in AWS Lambda, so the more efficient I can make it, the less I will have to pay for it.

Comment: @KristianBarrett I had no problem with your approach, var result = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<SimplePocoClass>(sr); using simple class , just FYI