# System Text Json read single object from array of objects

Tags: json, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to use the new System Text Json Library to read a single object from my json array.
My json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "test1",
    "Version": "16.0.461",
  },
  {
    "Id": "test2",
    "Version": "2.1.0",
  }
]
```

This is just an example. One Json Object actually has around 12 propteries. But suppose there is an class in c#, which looks like this:

```
     public class Data
     {
            public string Id { set; get; }
            public string Version { set; get; }
     }
```

and I'd like to just get the package where the id matches the given namen, which I tried like this:

```
    private static ObjectData GetSingleData(string jsonString, string objectName)
    {
                var options = new JsonDocumentOptions
                {
                    AllowTrailingCommas = true
                };

                using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString, options))
                {
                    ArrayEnumerator arrayEnumerator = document.RootElement.EnumerateArray();
                    //ObjectEnumerator objectEnumerator1 = document.RootElement.EnumerateObject();
                    while (arrayEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        JsonElement current = arrayEnumerator.Current;
                        if (objectName.Equals(current.GetProperty("id"))) 
                        {
                            //here the conversion from current to object should happen, but I don't know how                      
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
     }
```

is there a possiblity to convert a JsonElement to a instance of my *Data* Class?

Comment: Have you tried deserializing instead of trying to access the elements one by one? Eg `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Item[]>(json,options);`

Comment: This does work, but I thought I could deserialize just until the point, where I find the correct element instead of deserializing my whole jsonstring.

Comment: `JsonDocument.Parse` parses the entire document too.

Comment: Is there a possiblity to circumevent this?

Comment: You can use Utf8JsonReader to read elements one by one, but that works with UTF8 sequences in the form of `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` and `byte[]`. You'll have to use `varbytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);`, or read directly from a UTF8 JSON file. What are you trying to do in the first place? System.Text.Json isn't a general-purpose JSON parser yet, it's meant for Web app serialization, where the payload *is* UTF8 and has to be parsed/deserialized entirely before it gets consumed.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to circumvent parsing the whole array if I just need one single object at the beginning of the array. But it seems like this is not really possible, or I don't really understand how to approach this.

Comment: No.   Note parsing is pretty fast its generating the many parsing objects for further querying that's costly .. 
https://stu.dev/a-look-at-jsondocument/ has some more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138793/system-text-json-jsonelement-toobject-workaround)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
JsonElement current = document.RootElement;  
if (objectName.Equals(current.GetProperty("Id"))) 
{
     //But i'm using TryGetProperty
     //This is example code for first element in JSON array
     string id = current[0].GetProperty("Id").GetString(); //test1
     string version = current[0].GetProperty("Version").GetString(); //16.0.461
     
     //And now you can create your Data object
     Data data_object = new Data(id, version)
}
```

If I understand you correctly this should work.

**UPD:**
I don't recommend that you use the standard library, so use Json.NET instead , this library is very convenient and works faster (for example, I achieved deserialization speed to ~0.2 seconds [link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26383831/13940541))
**UPD 2:**
For .NET 5:

- [For migration from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)
- [Serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Answer (score 0):

**.NET 6** has `JsonElement.Deserialize<T>()`. [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047063/1275774)

```
var obj = current.Deserialize<ObjectData>();
```