# Efficient Manual Deserialization of Nested objects from Json using Newtonsoft in c#

Tags: c#, json, performance, serialization, json.net

I have this mesh that I want to read as fast as possible from json.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Mesh
{
    public int[] Faces { get; set; }
    public Vec3[] Vertices { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Vec3
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

I've read that creating a manual Serializer and Deserializer is [much faster](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) than [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26383831/14625617). So I tried to create my own:

```cs
public static Mesh FromJson(JsonTextReader reader)
{
    var mesh = new Mesh();
    var currentProperty = string.Empty;
    List<int> faces = new List<int>();
    List<Vec3> Vertices = new List<Vec3>();
    double X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Value != null)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                currentProperty = reader.Value.ToString();

            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer && currentProperty == "Faces")
                faces.Add(Int32.Parse(reader.Value.ToString()));

            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float && currentProperty == "X")
            {
                X = float.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
            }

            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float && currentProperty == "Y")
            {
                Y = float.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
            }

            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float && currentProperty == "Z")
            {
                Z = float.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject && reader.Path.Contains("Vertices"))
                Vertices.Add(new Vec3 { X = X, Y = Y, Z = Z });

        }
    }

    mesh.Faces = faces.ToArray();
    mesh.Vertices = Vertices.ToArray();
    return mesh;
}
```

Even though I managed to get a good 30% improvement (was expecting a bit more TBH) while Writing, reading is giving me trouble. I feel it has to do with the nesting of `Vec3` because if I run a similar logic but without `Vec3` I am getting decent results ~30%. The only examples I could find were dealing with simple data structures without nesting such as this so I feel I am handling it a bit simplistic here.

Comment: 1) Does your current code work?  1) Can you share an example of what the JSON looks like? 3) Json.NET [caches all reflection results in its contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182) so the overhead from reflection isn't as bad as you might think.  There's a one-time penalty for building the contract for a given type but if you are deserializing many instances then the penalty gets amortized.

Comment: You do have bugs in how you are parsing X, Y and Z though.

Comment: @dbc To answer your questions, now that you answered mine (lol)! My code works, but it is slower than the default deserialization. I notice that it takes around 4-6 second to deserialize a big chunk of data from a more complex structure and did a bit more investigation. You are right about X, Y, Z I thought since I couldn't find ```JsonToken.double``` to use floats, I can always change my data model if that is fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 30% speed-up when replacing automatic deserialization with manual deserialization is not unexpected.  Json.NET [caches all reflection results in its contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182) so the overhead from reflection isn't as bad as you might think.  There's a one-time penalty for building the contract for a given type but if you are deserializing a large file then the penalty gets amortized and the resulting contract provides delegates for fast getting and setting of property values.

That being said, I see the following issues (bugs and possible optimizations) with your code:

1. As you read through the JSON, you aren't keeping track of the parsing state.  This requires you to do `reader.Path.Contains("Vertices")` which is not performant.  It also makes your code vulnerable to unexpected behaviors when the JSON data is not as expected.
2. You are checking string equality for the `currentProperty`, but if you were to add all the expected property names to a [`DefaultJsonNameTable`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultJsonNameTable.htm) and set it at [`JsonTextReader.PropertyNameTable`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader_PropertyNameTable.htm) you would be able to replace those checks with reference equality checks, saving some time and some memory allocations.

   Note that PropertyNameTable was added in Json.NET [12.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/12.0.1).
3. `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are doubles, but you are parsing them **as floats**:

   ```
   X = float.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
   ```

   This is a bug that will cause accuracy loss.  What's more, you are parsing them in the **current culture** (which might have a localized decimal separator) rather than the invariant culture, which is another bug.
4. In any event there is no need to parse the `reader.Value` as a `double` because it already should be a `double`.  And in the case of an integer value, it should already be a `long`.  Simply converting to the required primitive type should be sufficient and faster.
5. Disabling [automatic date recognition](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_DateParseHandling.htm) may save you some time.

The following version of `FromJson()` resolves these issues:

```
public static partial class MeshExtensions
{
    const string Vertices = "Vertices";
    const string Faces = "Faces";
    const string X = "X";
    const string Y = "Y";
    const string Z = "Z";

    public static Mesh FromJson(JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        var nameTable = new DefaultJsonNameTable();
        nameTable.Add(Vertices);
        nameTable.Add(Faces);
        nameTable.Add(X);
        nameTable.Add(Y);
        nameTable.Add(Z);
        reader.PropertyNameTable = nameTable;  // For performance
        reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;  // Possibly for performance.

        bool verticesFound = false;
        List<Vec3> vertices = null;
        bool facesFound = false;
        List<int> faces = null;

        while (reader.ReadToContent())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && reader.Value == (object)Vertices)
            {
                if (verticesFound)
                    throw new JsonSerializationException("Multiple vertices");
                reader.ReadToContentAndAssert(); // Advance past the property name
                vertices = ReadVertices(reader); // Read the vertices array
                verticesFound = true;
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && reader.Value == (object)Faces)
            {
                if (facesFound)
                    throw new JsonSerializationException("Multiple faces");
                reader.ReadToContentAndAssert(); // Advance past the property name
                faces = reader.ReadIntArray(); // Read the vertices array
                facesFound = true;
            }
        }

        return new Mesh
        {
            Vertices = vertices == null ? null : vertices.ToArray(),
            Faces = faces == null ? null : faces.ToArray(),
        };
    }

    static List<Vec3> ReadVertices(JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token type {0}", reader.TokenType));
        var vertices = new List<Vec3>();
        while (reader.ReadToContent())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return vertices;

                case JsonToken.Null:
                    // Or throw an exception if you prefer.
                    //throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token type {0}", reader.TokenType));
                    vertices.Add(null);
                    break;

                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    var vertex = ReadVertex(reader);
                    vertices.Add(vertex);
                    break;

                default:
                    // reader.Skip();
                    throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token type {0}", reader.TokenType));
            }
        }
        throw new JsonReaderException(); // Truncated file.
    }

    static Vec3 ReadVertex(JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            throw new JsonException();
        var vec = new Vec3();
        while (reader.ReadToContent())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return vec;

                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    if (reader.Value == (object)X)
                        vec.X = reader.ReadAsDouble().Value;
                    else if (reader.Value == (object)Y)
                        vec.Y = reader.ReadAsDouble().Value;
                    else if (reader.Value == (object)Z)
                        vec.Z = reader.ReadAsDouble().Value;
                    else // Skip unknown property names and values.
                        reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().Skip();
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token type {0}", reader.TokenType));
            }
        }
        throw new JsonReaderException(); // Truncated file.
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static List<int> ReadIntArray(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonReaderException(string.Format("Unexpected token type {0}", reader.TokenType));

        var list = new List<int>();
        // ReadAsInt32() reads the next token as an integer, skipping comments
        for (var value = reader.ReadAsInt32(); true; value = reader.ReadAsInt32())
        {
            if (value != null)
                list.Add(value.Value);
            else 
                // value can be null if we reached the end of the array, encountered a null value, or encountered the end of a truncated file.
                // JsonReader will throw an exception on most types of malformed file, but not on a truncated file.
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.EndArray:
                        return list;
                    case JsonToken.Null:
                    default:
                        throw new JsonReaderException(string.Format("Unexpected token type {0}", reader.TokenType));
                }
        }
    }

    public static bool ReadToContent(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            return false;
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            if (!reader.Read())
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        return reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();
    }

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kUaBTO). As you can see properly handling boundary conditions such as comments, unexpected properties and truncated streams makes writing robust manual deserialization code tricky.

Comment: Wow! Lots of things to get out of this! Thank you very much I think this is more than answering my questions. I guess the takeaways is that it requires quite a bit more code to write and is probably worth doing it once you have figure out all your data models. 30% still seems little but I guess this goes to show how much work they've put on the default serializer.

p.s. Do you think another library might also help?

Comment: @Stam - so in the end, how much faster was the version in my answer for deserializing your actual data?

Comment: @Stam - *Do you think another library might also help?* Microsoft claims [tag:system.text.json] is faster, but it's not easy to work with.  For instance it doesn't support non-async deserialization from a `Stream`.  You could take a look at https://michaelscodingspot.com/the-battle-of-c-to-json-serializers-in-net-core-3/ and https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2019/09/29/net-serialization-benchmark-2019-roundup/ for some interesting benchmarks.  But be sure to test for yourself, see https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: sorry for the late answer! It was 30% on the tests, but I haven't yet tried a real world performance though. Unfortunately the serialization is but a small part of this app.